# Guest Payment Support in Embedded Payment Flow for Preapprovals

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

We are currently redirecting our users to PayPal in order to accept a Preapproval (Adaptive Payments). There, the user can log in to PayPal or just enter his Credit Card information.

If instead of redirecting the user we use the 'embedded flow' (lightbox or new window), the user can login or signup only.

How to let the user insert their Credit Card info in the embedded flow?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Preapprovals with Adaptive Payments you can't use guest checkout, i.e. your users will need either to log-in with their Paypal account or to create one.

I know it sucks, but as far as I know there is no workaround.